# Woocommerce - Call custom function after payment is completed

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce for some project and i need to send the order id to some remote site when the payment is made. I am not finding the accurate hook to do this. Can anyone help me to find what's the correct hook to perform certain action after order is completed.

Here is what i have tried

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'woo_remote_order' );

function woo_remote_order( $order_id ) {

// Lets grab the order
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );


//Some action to make sure its working.

wp_mail( 'sagarseth9@example.com',' Woocommmerce Order ID is '.$order_id , 'Woocommerce order' );

}
```

Not sure which is the proper hook to perform this action. I am using paypal payment gateway for payment and orders successfully passes through.

Comment: I would actually recommend doing that with PayPal IPN instead of doing it within WooCommerce.  IPN will trigger when a payment is completed, refunded, in a pending status, cleared from pending status, dispute left, etc.  It covers a lot more than just the original order and is a very useful tool.

Answer (score 6):

looks like you need add accepted_args on last parameters,
Try this :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'your_func', 10, 1 );

function your_func($order_id) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    /* Do Something with order ID */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try one of the following.

- woocommerce_checkout_order_processed
- woocommerce_new_order

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_payment_complete', 'YourFunction', 1, 2);  
function YourFunction ($order_id)
  {
  $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
  wp_mail( 'sagarseth9@example.com',' Woocommmerce Order ID is '.$order_id , 'Woocommerce order' );

  }
```

The add_action call must be placed at the very beginning of your plugin, if using wordpress, or if a theme, in functions.php.